# Change MS Excel Row Colour in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am currently creating a small program that will allow a user to input data into a windows form. Once this data has been input into the form it will then be added to a Excel Document using OleDb.

I have no problems with the above section and I can input data no bother however my problem comes when I try to change the colour of the Excel Row.

I am looking to change the colour of the row to red if the row currently has no fill.

The code I am currently using:

```
        Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\jhughes\Desktop\ScreenUpdate.xls");
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["DailyWork"];
        Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
        Excel.Range rows = usedRange.Rows;
        try
        {
            foreach (Excel.Range row in rows)
            {
              if (row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0)
              {
                 row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
              }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

I am getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool" at the line "If(row.Cells.EntireRow....)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you not added saving to workbook and change in if condition. Somehow the default colorindex is coming as -4142. Tested now able to change the change color

```
Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\MyPath\Desktop\ColorBook.xls");
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["DailyWork"];
                Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
                Excel.Range rows = usedRange.Rows;
                try
                {
                    foreach (Excel.Range row in rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex == -4142)
                        {
                            row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        }
                    }
                    workbook.Save();
                    workbook.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to set the `ColorIndex` to `0`, not comparing it to `0`.  Use `==` when you compare.

```
foreach (Excel.Range row in rows)
{
    if (row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex == 0) // changed = to ==
    {
        row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea...Of all the small errors that's the one that got me. That has removed the Error however no rows in my spreadsheet are being converted to red.

Comment: I'm sorry - I was answering more to the c#-edness of the post - I don't have any specific excel experience.  Is there any kind of method to flush your changes back to the form?  Something like an `OnPropertyChanged` from the WPF technology?  +1 for visibility.

Comment: I'll look into OnPropertyChanged thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) instead of [`=` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx). `==` operator for equality but `=` operator is for assignment.

```
if (row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex == 0)
```

`=` operators simply assign right operand to the left variable/property/indexer and returns the value as its result. That's why when you write

```
if (row.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0)
```

it is equal to

```
if(0)
```

which is won't compile since [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664746%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) expects [boolean expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression).